# grouping non-zero entries in a matrix according to a rule

Tags: matrices, algorithms, parsing

I have a matrix say, $a = \left[\matrix{ 0 & 1 & 0& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
                           0& 0 &0 &0 &0 &1& 1\\
                           1& 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
                           0 &1 &0 &0 &0 &0& 0\\
                           0 &0 &1 &0 &1& 0& 0\\
                           0& 0& 0 &1 &0 &0 &1}\right]$

I need to enumerate the non-zero elements into groups according to the following:
- if two elements share a row or a column they are in the same group, and if say (1,2) & (1,6) in group1, then group1 will also include (2,6) & (2,7) & (6,7) & (4,2), I have been stuck with this fr a while, any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I did not know which section would this go into, thought mathematics was the closest? matrix a is 6x7 in the above example

Comment: I still don't know what you are asking.

Comment: So you want an algorithm to do the grouping for you? In that case I would ask the computer scientists... but it shouldn't be too hard: just find the first 1, add every one in its row and column, repeat until exhausted. Then find any 1 that may still be remaining, do the same process. Repeat, etc. until all 1's in the matrix have been put into groups.

Comment: I have a matrix, that contain a flag of value one for resource sharing, rows are consumers, and columns are resources, if there is  1 at a(2,1) it means consumer one is accessing resource 2, and so on. now there is a many to many relationship, meaning that many consumers could be sharing a pool of resources. and this is what I meant by the groups above.

Answer (score 1):

As det has pointed out, although you got most of the entries needed in Group 1, you missed $(6, 4)$, being in the same row as $(6, 7)$. After verifying that there are no more that need to go in Group 1, go on to making Group 2. Hint: There are only three entries left to place into groups, namely $(3, 1)$, $(5, 3)$, and $(5, 5)$.

Comment: thanks, the a matrix could be huge depending on the number of agent, is there an algorithm that is better than the brute force way.

Comment: You mean for programming? If you're doing it by hand, I don't think you're going to do much better than this; your brain is built to pick out patterns like two entries being in the same row and column. If you're programming it, that's a computer science question, and I strongly suspect depends heavily on the type of data structure being used.

Comment: another thing, if I go by two loops to search, I would miss (6,4) because I will reach (6,7) and the very end, and (6,7) is the one that would make (6,4) a memebr of the group

Comment: That's right; you need to check whether there are any other entries that are in the same row and column as any of the ones you've seen so far. You're not done with a given group until after you've done this for every entry encountered.

Comment: I see, thanks. I am using simple matlab matrices for now.

Comment: As someone said already, you should probably ask this on a cs forum instead.

Answer (score 0):

"if two elements share a row or a column they are in the same group" How?

"and if say (1,2) & (1,6) in group1, then group1 will also include (2,6) & (2,7) & (6,7) & (4,2)" Why not (6,4)?

Use MATLAB:

```
  % use the function [e1, e2] = find(a)
  e = find(a(i, :)~=0); % i = 1:size(a, 1), e is a vector of size the
  % number of ones in row i. e=[i1, i2, ..., ip]
  % Put in the 1st group the element a(i, e(i1:ip)).
  Group{k}={a(i, e(i1:ip))}; % k=1:...

  for i=1:size(a, 1)
     e{i} = find(a(i, 1)~=0);
  ...
```

Comment: (6,4) too, is in group1 too thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

the solution ended up making use of graph adjacency matrix, and disconnected graphs, credit goes to Matt J. on mathworks central:

[I,J]=find(a);
   C=bsxfun(@eq,I,I.') | bsxfun(@eq,J,J.');

The matrix C is a graph connectivity map which you can then use to segment into groups using this FEX file,

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33877-find-graph-conected-components